# ToastId undefined

Tags: angular, toastr

I am trying to implemeted the ngx-toastr in my angular 8 application and currently getting an error while trying to capture the toastId. Initially i can see the toastId while debuging but eventually when the break point hits inside the subscribe method, the toastData is undefined. I understand that the toastrService returns the ActiveToast interface. How do I resolve this issue

The error that I am getting is toastdata is undefined at line

```
this.stickyToasties.push(toastData.toastId);

stickyToasties: number[] = [];

showToast(message: AlertMessage, isSticky: boolean) {   
  if (message == null) {
    for (let id of this.stickyToasties.slice(0)) {
      this.toastrService.clear(id);
    }

    return;
  }

  // default value for message is 4 seconds
  var timeOutSeconds = message.timeOutSeconds ? message.timeOutSeconds * 1000 : 4000;

  var toastData = this.toastrService.success(message.summary, message.detail, { timeOut: isSticky ? 0 : timeOutSeconds });

  if (isSticky) {
    if( toastData) {
      toastData.onShown.subscribe((toastData) => {
        this.stickyToasties.push(toastData.toastId);
        })

      toastData.onHidden.subscribe((toastData) => {
        let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toastData.toastId, 0);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#toastr-service-methods-return), it appears as though the `success` method returns an `ActiveToast` interface. That interface contains the `onShown` and `onHidden` properties as you are utilizing in your post. It ***also*** includes the `toastId`.

`onShown` and `onHidden` return an `Observable<any>`. Their documentation doesn't specify which properties will be on that object, but based on how you are using it in your question, it shouldn't matter at the moment.

You are assigning the return value from `success` to `toastData`, but are then hiding that value inside `onShown` with the Observable value provided by that method. Given your code above, you should be able to update it to the following to get the error message to go away and achieve your desired results.

```
if (isSticky) {
  if(toastData) {
    toastData.onShown.subscribe(() => {
        this.stickyToasties.push(toastData.toastId);
        })

      toastData.onHidden.subscribe(() => {
        let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toastData.toastId, 0);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

If you actually plan to update the code to utilize the value recieved through `onHidden`, you could do this instead:

```
      toastData.onHidden.subscribe((onHiddenData) => {
        let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toastData.toastId, 0);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
        }
      })
```